# Trying to make sense of git fetch

Tags: git

Suppose that the repo at `$REPO_URL` has *multiple* branches, including one called `dev`.  Now, suppose I run the following commands, one right after the other

```
% git clone $REPO_URL --branch dev wd
% cd wd
% git branch -a
* dev
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/issue6
  remotes/origin/issue26
  remotes/origin/issue30
  ...
  remotes/origin/issue709
  remotes/origin/issue712
  remotes/origin/issue716
  remotes/origin/master
```

What must I do at this point so that for each branch of the form `remotes/origin/X` there's a local branch `X` that matches it exactly?  By this I mean that the following two commands would produce identical output:

```
% git rev-parse remotes/origin/X
% git rev-parse X
```

and also that the output of `git branch -a` would end up looking like this:

```
* dev
  issue6
  issue26
  issue30
  ...
  issue709
  issue712
  issue716
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/issue6
  remotes/origin/issue26
  remotes/origin/issue30
  ...
  remotes/origin/issue709
  remotes/origin/issue712
  remotes/origin/issue716
  remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: A simple shell script should be able to do that in no time...

Comment: The question is not about how one could achieve iteration.

Comment: Isn't that what any solution you use is going to have to do, though?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `fetch` for this, because you already did that when you cloned the repo.  What you want is a local branch to match each remote tracking branch, and for this you can use `checkout`:

```
git checkout -b issue6 origin/issue6
```

So you can have a script that loops through all remote branches and checks them out.

As mentioned in comments, recent versions of git can use a simpler command:

```
git checkout issue6
```

Comment: in recent versions of git, `git checkout issue6` will do the same thing.

Comment: So to create a branch one needs to check it out?

Comment: @kjo -- both of the above commands are syntactic sugar for creating a local branch then checking it out. The actual creation of a branch is still `git branch <branch name>`

Comment: @kjo, if you want to create the local branches without using checkout, you can use `git branch --track issue6 origin/issue6`.

Answer (score 2):

A shell for loop will do it:

```
for BRANCH in $(git branch -r | grep -v HEAD) # list of remote branches (excluding HEAD)
do
    git checkout --track ${BRANCH}
done
```